# Can't import(import com.android.internal.statusbar) statements in android system application

Tags: android, makefile, sdk, android-source, android.mk

Trying to remove notification bar from my system android application in AOSP.
But can not able to import (import com.android.internal.statusbar and The import android.app.StatusBarManager) in my code.

```
import com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarService;
import android.app.StatusBarManager;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StatusBarManager mStatusBarManager = (StatusBarManager) 
getSystemService(Context.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE);
        mStatusBarManager.disable(StatusBarManager.DISABLE_EXPAND);
}
```

> Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v13 \
    android-support-v17-leanback \
    android-support-v7-appcompat

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
    $(call all-java-files-under, WallpaperPicker/src) \
    $(call all-proto-files-under, protos)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/WallpaperPicker/res \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/res \

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

LOCAL_PROTOC_OPTIMIZE_TYPE := nano
LOCAL_PROTOC_FLAGS := --proto_path=$(LOCAL_PATH)/protos/
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
      --auto-add-overlay \
--extra-packages android.support.v7.recyclerview

 LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
 LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := PlayerLauncher
 LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

 LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home Launcher2
 include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, util) \
 $(call all-proto-files-under, protos)

 LOCAL_PROTOC_OPTIMIZE_TYPE := nano
 LOCAL_PROTOC_FLAGS := --proto_path=$(LOCAL_PATH)/protos/

 LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
 LOCAL_MODULE := launcher_protoutil_lib
 LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE := true
 LOCAL_JAR_MANIFEST := util/etc/manifest.txt

 include $(BUILD_HOST_JAVA_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE := true
  LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
  LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
  LOCAL_MODULE := launcher_protoutil

  include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/base_rules.mk

  $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): | 
  $(HOST_OUT_JAVA_LIBRARIES)/launcher_protoutil_lib.jar
  $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): $(LOCAL_PATH)/util/etc/launcher_protoutil | 
  $(ACP)
@echo "Copy: $(PRIVATE_MODULE) ($@)"
  $(copy-file-to-new-target)
  $(hide) chmod 755 $@
 INTERNAL_DALVIK_MODULES += $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE)
 include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

> Can you please help me to what type of libraries have add to in
>   Android.mk file.
>   Getting error while compiling system android application AOSP SDK .

build/core/Makefile:34: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/g9x/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl'
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/amlogic/g9x/hhs/gms/permissions/android.software.app_widgets.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.software.app_widgets.xml ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/amlogic/g9x/hhs/gms/permissions/android.hardware.location.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.location.xml ignored.
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE g9x
Building with Jack: out/target/common/obj/APPS/EvoPlayerLauncher_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex
Launching background server java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms2560m -XX:+TieredCompilation -jar out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack-launcher.jar -cp out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack.jar com.android.jack.server.JackSimpleServer
VANILLA/vendor/amlogic/apps/PlayerLauncher/src/com/android/playerlauncher/MainActivity.java:5: The import com.android.internal.statusbar  cannot be resolved
VANILLA/vendor/amlogic/apps/PlayerLauncher/src/com/android/playerlauncher/MainActivity.java:6: The import android.app.StatusBarManager cannot be resolved
VANILLA/vendor/amlogic/apps/PlayerLauncher/src/com/android/playerlauncher/MainActivity.java:45: StatusBarManager cannot be resolved to a type
VANILLA/vendor/amlogic/apps/PlayerLauncher/src/com/android/playerlauncher/MainActivity.java:45: StatusBarManager cannot be resolved to a type
VANILLA/vendor/amlogic/apps/PlayerLauncher/src/com/android/playerlauncher/MainActivity.java:45: STATUS_BAR_SERVICE cannot be resolved or is not a field
VANILLA/vendor/amlogic/apps/PlayerLauncher/src/com/android/playerlauncher/MainActivity.java:46: StatusBarManager cannot be resolved to a variable
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/PlayerLauncher_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex] Error 41
make: Leaving directory`/media/VANILLA'

Comment: u mean status bar like full screen app

Comment: Yes...HemalHerath and i have added   LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v13 \
    android-support-v17-leanback \
    android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html check this

Comment: This link is for hiding notification bar,But I need to do completely remove notification bar and i have updated my question ,could you please check..  HemalHerath

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: why do u want to remove that by hiding that u can do the same work as remove

Comment: If will swipe down notification bar show not open.Here my problem is apk is not generating and getting error like can't import(import android.app.StatusBarManager;  ) file.

Comment: Im sorry man I have never done what u asking, I think you should delete this question and ask the same question with brief explaination

Comment: OK..Thank you..I have changed my question.

Comment: `com.android.internal.*` is not part of public API of android. You should use something like `reflection` in java or create a `stub` to bypass compiler . Linking process is actually happens in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is privileged (has system permissions), but does not yet have access to the system APIs (such as `android.app.StatusBarManager`). In order to get access, you need your app to be signed using the platform certificate.

Add this to your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```